# React how to jump to a target input area in a form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, validation, input

I had a very long form which around 20 different fields and I displayed those input area using map function. I want to valid the input data when I click the submit button and jump to the corresponding input required box.

```
const ReportFields = [
  {
      title: "Report Title*",
      field: "report_title",
      type: "text",
      required: true
  },
  {
      title: "Submitting Agency*",
      field: "submitting_agency",
      type: "text",
      required: true
  },
  {
      title: "Division*",
      field: "division",
      type: "select",
      required: true
  },
  {
      title: "Committee*",
      field: "committee",
      type: "select",
      required: true
  },
  {
      title: "Assigned Contact*",
      field: "assigned_contact",
      type: "select",
      required: true
  },
  {
      title: "Other Recipients",
      field: "other_recipients",
      type: "text",
      required: false
  }];

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    report: {
    report_title: "",
    submitting_agency: "",
    division: "",
    committee: "",
    assigned_contact: "",
    other_recipients: ""
    },
    errorMessage: "",
    refs: {}
  }

 componentDidMount() {
    this.registerRefs();
 }

 registerRefs = () => {
    const refs = ReportFields.reduce((acc, current) => {
      const ref = React.createRef();
      acc[current.field] = ref;
      return acc;
    }, {});

    this.setState({ refs });
 }

   onSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      for (let i = 0; i < ReportFields.length; i++) {
      const curt = ReportFields[i];
      if (curt.required && this.state.report[curt.field] === "") {
        this.setState({errorMessage: `${curt.title} cannot be empty!`});
        this.state.refs[curt.field].current.focus();
        break;
      }
    }
  }

   render() {
     const display = ReportFields.map((field, idx) => {
     return (
       <div key={idx}>
         <p>{field.title}</p>
         <input 
            type={field.type}
            onChange={(e) => {
              this.setState({
                 report: {...this.state.report, [field.field]: e.target.value}
            })
        }}
        ref={this.state.refs[field.field]}
        ></input>
      </div>
    );
})

    return (
      <div className="App">
        {display}
        <input type="button" value="submit" onClick={this.onSubmit}/>
      </div>
    );
 }
}

 export default App;
```

I tried to use react refs but it doesn't work, any idea?

Also, I am actually using these content in react modal, will this be one of the reason why it doesn't work?

Comment: Can you show how you try to make it work with ref ?

Comment: I followed the instruction here https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html. And the ref creation is already in the code.

Comment: The problem is here you map and build your input with that, so the refs can't know which input this is, cause here you have 20 field with the same ref.

Comment: Then if I want to create the ref for each of those field, is there a way that I can do it in the map function? Or I will have to create them under the constructor one by one?

Comment: Working on the solution, shouldn't not be long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here is a solution I know who can work but I don't say it's the best one. A working example here https://codesandbox.io/s/94v4r6w7kr. As you can see when you click submit you jump to password input.

How do that work ? First as you can see we need a way to save all the ref we gonna create. I save it in the state refs here. The way that work is a loop over each field and for each one I createRef and add this to an object. I use this object inside the state. When you want to use it after that, you then can call `this.state.refs[thenameoftheinput].current.focus()`.

This is an example, and I let you make it work with your own data. But I hope that can give you an idea :)

```
const ReportFields = [
  {
    title: "Report Title*",
    field: "report_title",
    type: "text",
    required: true
  },
  {
    title: "Submitting Agency*",
    field: "submitting_agency",
    type: "text",
    required: true
  },
  {
    title: "Division*",
    field: "division",
    type: "select",
    required: true
  },
  {
    title: "Committee*",
    field: "committee",
    type: "select",
    required: true
  },
  {
    title: "Assigned Contact*",
    field: "assigned_contact",
    type: "select",
    required: true
  },
  {
    title: "Other Recipients",
    field: "other_recipients",
    type: "text",
    required: false
  }
];

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      refs: {}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.registerRefs();
  }

  registerRefs = () => {
    const refs = ReportFields.reduce((acc, current) => {
      const ref = React.createRef();
      acc[current.field] = ref;
      return acc;
    }, {});

    this.setState({ refs });
  };

  focusTextInput = () => {
    this.state.refs.division.current.focus();
  };

  render() {
    const inputs = ReportFields.map(el => {
      return <input placeholder={el.title} ref={this.state.refs[el.field]} />;
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          {inputs}
          <input type="button" value="submit" onClick={this.focusTextInput} />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I edited the code and it gave me the error of cannot read property 'focus' of null. Is there sth wrong with my definition for ref?

Comment: @fancylynn I made the change on my example, so you can try it. Didn't see you provide the value :S Sorry about that

Comment: Your solution is correct. It was just because i didn't give the correct reference name in the map function. Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: Perfect :) Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through all fields and create a separate ref for each one of them. Use a unique identifier (as a suggestion - the name property) to access the ref later.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.focusTextInput = this.focusTextInput.bind(this);

    // Fields
    this.ReportFields = [
      {
        type: "text",
        name: "firstname",
        title: "First Name"
      },
      {
        type: "text",
        name: "lastname",
        title: "Last Name"
      }
    ];

    this.inputRefs = this.ReportFields.reduce((acc, field) => ({
        ...acc,
        [field.name]: React.createRef()
      }), {}); 
  }

  state = {
    a: {
      b: "",
      c: "",
      d: "",
      e: "",
      f: "",
      g: "",
      h: "",
      i: "",
      j: "",
      k: "",
      l: "",
      m: "",
      n: "",
      o: "",
      p: "",
      q: "",
      r: "",
      s: "",
      t: "",
      u: "",
      v: "",
      w: "",
      x: "",
      y: ""
    },
    errorMessage: ""
  };

  focusTextInput() {

    // Focus on the input you wish, in this case "firstname"
    console.log(this.inputRefs["firstname"].current.focus());
  }

  render() {
    const display = this.ReportFields.map((field, idx) => {
      return (
        <div key={idx}>
          <p>{field.title}</p>
          <input
            type={field.type}
            onChange={e => {
              this.setState({
                report: { ...this.state.report, [field.field]: e.target.value }
              });
            }}
            ref={this.inputRefs[field.name]}
          />
        </div>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div className="App">
        {display}
        <input type="button" value="submit" onClick={this.focusTextInput} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```